# Countdown which use server timestamp and service-worker lagging. How to solve?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, service-worker, countdown, tradingview-api

Im developing an application, where user need to do some action until countdown will be finished.

Website countdown should be sync with TradingViews' candle countdown 
[image]

- As a 1st option I tried to use `new Date()`, but it works incorrect if browser time is changed. Even 10s different between **Tradingview time** and **Application time** can be critical.
- As a 2nd option I fetch server time from application API, and increase that value with simple `setInterval()` method, but sometime it lags with 10-20 seconds.

  `let timestamp = await getServerTime()
  setInterval(() => {
      timestamp++;
      this.currentTimestamp = timestamp
  }, 1000);`
- As a 3rd option I tried to use `service-worker` for the same `setInterval()` method, and push updated value to component. This option also start lags after long using.

---

I read many advises, but non of them help to solve this case.
Do you know any method to use server side time correctly, without lagging?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `moment.js` library and the method called `locale` to get the locale user and to calculate the duration you can use the method `duration`